# Database Schema relationship design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

[image]

Hi there,

I'm new to database design and I'm trying to design a very simple schema for the model.

Just wondering if this will be the best way to design it, since this is my first time and don't want to build this out without a lookover.

`Pokemon table:`

- I get the `name, id (PK), type(FK), image and regionID(fk)`
- `type` is a Foreign Key from the `Type` table and has a `one-to-many` relationship. Does that sound right? I'm thinking this because `one pokemon can have multiple types`? Also `multiple pokemon can have multiple` types makes sense to me.
- `regionID` is a foreign key from `Region` table. `many pokemon can live in many regions` makes sense to me. Or should it be `one pokemon can live in multiple regions`? Or `multiple regions can have multiple pokemon`?

`Region table:`

- I've only got a `PK` in here. Do I need the FK from `LocationWithinRegion` table as well?
- I have a `one to many` relationship here, Because `1 region can have multiple locations` but `one location can't have multiple regions`. Is this right?

`Type table`:

- I made all those types bits so I can represent a boolean value. I want to be able to query the pokemon table and look for all related data and find true or false in regions where that pokemon can be found.

This is my first time making a database schema so please, let me know how it looks!

Thanks

Comment: pokmontype primary key type need to match with FK of pokmon table

Comment: Looks like it is already. The `PK` of `Type table` is a `FK` in the pokemon table.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- Provide each table with a singular name. `User` not `Users` as each
  row represents a User.
- Provide each table with the smallest possible primary key. In most
  cases an identity int would do.
- Create an index on foreign key columns. This will help joins.

Now in your case:

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Pokemon` and `Type`. So I would drop the `PokemonType string` from the `Pokemon` table and I would create a table `Type(Id int Identity PK, Description string Unique)` and a table `PokemonType(PokemonId int FK on Pokemon, TypeId int FK on Type, PK on both columns)`

Also is a many-to-many relationship between `Pokemon` and `Region`.

In general, to represent a many-to-many relationship, you need a lookup table between the two tables.

Something like A(id) -> Lookup(A.id, B.id) <- B(id)